# Elpy Auto Complete is not working at all

Tags: auto-complete-mode, elpy

I am trying to configure my emacs for python programming. Elpy auto-complete suggestion is not working at all in all instances. Any suggestions?

Here is my `elpy-config`...

```
Elpy Configuration

Emacs.............: 26.3
Elpy..............: 1.31.0
Virtualenv........: None
Interactive Python: python 3.7.4 (/Users/mdmorshed/.pyenv/shims/python)
RPC virtualenv....: rpc-venv (/Users/mdmorshed/.emacs.d/elpy/rpc-venv)
 Python...........: python 3.7.4 (/Users/mdmorshed/.emacs.d/elpy/rpc-venv/bin/python)
 Jedi.............: 0.15.1
 Rope.............: 0.14.0
 Autopep8.........: 1.4.4
 Yapf.............: 0.28.0
 Black............: 19.3b0
Syntax checker....: flake8 (/usr/local/bin/flake8)

You have not activated a virtual env. While Elpy supports this, it is
often a good idea to work inside a virtual env. You can use M-x
pyvenv-activate or M-x pyvenv-workon to activate a virtual env.

The directory ~/.local/bin/ is not in your PATH. As there is no active
virtualenv, installing Python packages locally will place executables
in that directory, so Emacs won't find them. If you are missing some
commands, do add this directory to your PATH -- and then do
`elpy-rpc-restart'.
```

Answer (score 2):

[The online help of Elpy](https://elpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ide.html#completion) says:

> Elpy uses Company Mode for the completion interface, so its documentation is a good place for further information.

The most probable explanation is that `company` is not installed, or not correctly tweaked in your `init.el` file.

Make sure that `company` is installed and then try to add the following line in your init file:

`(add-hook 'after-init-hook 'global-company-mode)`